# How to trigger a WebHook when a Public Github repo that I do not own gets a new commit?

Tags: github, git-commit, github-webhook

Is it possible to trigger a webhook whenever a public Github repo gets a new commit. I tried seeing on Zapier and other automation tools, but all of them require me to be an owner of that repo.